# What is username or password for elasticsearch window "localhost:9200"

Tags: elasticsearch, magento

I'm trying to install elastic search for Magneto-2.4. When I run localhost:9200 it is asking for username and password in window and don't know about. Please help me to resolve this issue.

**My elastic search version is 8.3.2**

Please help me to fix this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create a pasword using: C:\elasticsearch-8.3.2\bin>\bin\elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic

cf:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/zip-windows.html#windows-service

Comment: now I'm getting this message 
Professional@DESKTOP-8N1GE4T MINGW64 /e/xampp-new/htdocs/elasticsearch-8.3.2-windows-x86_64/elasticsearch-8.3.2/bin
$ elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic
bash: elasticsearch-reset-password: command not found

Comment: Is there any other way to run this without username or password??

Comment: I thinck service is notstart, follow the link.

default password is: password
default usernoame: elasticsearch or elastic

You can also disable authen, just comment xpack.security in config/elasticsearch.yml file (and restart elasticsearch).

Comment: [2022-07-18T21:21:58,480][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.RealmsAuthenticator] [DESKTOP-8N1GE4T] Authentication of [elastic] was terminated by realm [reserved] - failed to authenticate user [elastic]

Comment: this I'm getting in my cmd

Comment: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"","ApiKey"]}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"","ApiKey"]}},"status":401}

Answer (score 2):

I was also stuck at the same thing. But I will suggest for local and learning level you can disable the password.

It is a 2 step process:

1. Go to config folder in elasticsearch and open elasticsearch.yml.
2. There add the line :
   **xpack.security.enabled:false** Or make it false if true.

Now restart your elastic search server.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to execute below command inside elasticsearch folder to set the password

```
C:\elasticsearch-8.8.0\bin>bin\elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic
```

After this, while installing magento, you will need to add parameters related to elasticsearch

```
--elasticsearch-enable-auth=1 --elasticsearch-username=elastic --elasticsearch-password=+n48xxxxxxxxxxxF1I
```

ie

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://hemant.magento.com/" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento2" --db-user="root" --db-password="root" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="user@example.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="Admin@123456" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin" --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host="localhost" --elasticsearch-port=9200 --elasticsearch-enable-auth=1 --elasticsearch-username=elastic --elasticsearch-password=+n48xxxxxxxxxxxF1I
```

After this, it gave error as "Catalog Search index process error during indexation process" for indexing command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

To resolve this, installed elasticsearch Version 7, because elasticsearch   version 8.0 wasn't supported by Magento.